# How to commit emojis using android IME

Tags: android, ime

I am looking to add emojis using a soft keyboard i am experimenting with. I am aware the default keyboard in android allows entering Emojis.

However when i am trying to commit a string with an emoji it shows up a junk character on the edit text.

Is there some thing i am missing?
I am doing the following to commit an emoji :

```
        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(String.valueOf((char)58389),0);
```

Same is the case with the emoji keyboard here : https://github.com/zeuxisoo/android-emoji-keyboard

[image]

Comment: check this out https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an IME. Can you please guide me what to look for on this repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem.
The emojis are 32bit unicode characters. Hence one has to send 2 16bit characters to commitText to commit an emoji. Something like :

```
getCurrentInputConnection().commitText("\ud83d\ude01", 1)
```